# Is there a solution for using ASP.NET MVC 5 Html.EditorFor() and Bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

**Question:**

Is there a way to make the ASP.NET MVC 5 Html.EditorFor() form helpers work with the changed [Bootstrap 3 form syntax](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).*?

**Discussion** (of what I have looked into already):

It appears there are a many SO questions regarding hacks to override the built in MVC helpers. In general, it doesn't look like there is a supported solution to modify the helper HTML. (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Therefore, is it possible to build a shim CSS file that adapts the Helper's 2.3.x HTML to the look of the Bootstrap 3 form CSS? It seems that most other aspects of MVC 5 are Bootstrap 3 compatible except for the auto form fields.

The benefit of a CSS shim, is that it could be removed when ASP.NET MVC is updated to support the newer Bootstrap syntax natively.

*I acknowledge that ASP.NET MVC 5 is still in beta and has been developed for Bootstrap 2.3.x since 3.0 was also in beta at the time.

Comment: I have heard that the RTM of MVC 5 will include support for Bootstrap 3.0, although I cannot find that blog post or release note at the moment. If you have info on this, please post a link.

Comment: Dan, have you figured out a solution since you posted this? We are now encountering the same problem you describe where we can't attach the new Bootstrap 3 `form-control` class to inputs rendered with Html.EditorFor(). Are we still SOL?

Comment: Frankly, I haven't checked recently. I meant to re-test this issue once the final version of Visual Studio 2013 came out to see if there was any improvements. Have you checked to see if there are an NuGet updates available for your bootstrap and MVC components?

Comment: We just upgraded our solution to use MVC 5 and manually integrated Bootstrap 3, but as far as I'm aware, there is still no way to get HTML attributes into an EditorFor without doing a custom attribute implementation or something. Just didn't know if you had any luck with any other solution. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is now a MS solution for the MVC helpers.

<strike>It's currently **Pre-release**, but MVC5.1 has</strike>

MVC 5.1 is released and has

> **Bootstrap support in views**
>
> We now allow passing in html attributes in EditorFor as an anonymous object

Example code...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })
```

More info on this here....
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-and-web-tools-20132-preview-for-visual-studio-2013-release-notes#mvcbootstrap

.. and install instructions here...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/09/asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-2-preview-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: Note that this update has now been released formally..
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/20/announcing-the-release-of-asp-net-mvc-5-1-asp-net-web-api-2-1-and-asp-net-web-pages-3-1.aspx

Answer (score 8):

TwitterBootstrapMVC looks like a good abstraction over Bootstrap 3 - great with the Fluent API, BUT sending credit card details for a trial? Nope.

Answer (score 2):

[TwitterBootstrapMVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc) is a library of html helpers, main focus of which is to simplify writing html related to Twitter Bootstrap forms.

As of today it works with Twitter Bootstrap 2 syntax. However, support for Twitter Bootstrap 3 will be released shortly.

If you used helpers from tihs library, transition from v2 to v3 should be painless.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of TwitterBootstrapMVC
The BMVC for Bootstrap 3 is not free.

Comment: Worth to mention it is a paid library.